# Handling questions about selenium for web-scraping

Tags: discussion, selenium

Recently, this question was asked on the SQA site: [python selenium webdriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30711/python-selenium-webdriver).

It is about all a Python script that uses Selenium to extract some data from a website. But, even though Selenium is used in test automation, I feel that this particular question is off-topic since it has nothing to do with Quality Assurance.

Just wanted to reach out and see if there is any sense in my logic here. Should we close the question proposing to ask it on StackOverflow instead?

Answer (score 3):

There was, once upon a time, a proposal for a Selenium-only site. That site got merged into this site, with the expectation that all content from that site would be allowed on ours.

So I would say we would allow it because of that history. But in this matter I'm just a longtime user, not an authority.